# Elementary way to show $\mathbb{Z}[e^{2 \pi i / 5}]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[X] / (X^4 + X^3 + X^2 + X + 1)$ are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I'd like to show that $\mathbb{Z}[e^{2 \pi i / 5}]$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[X] / (X^4 + X^3 + X^2 + X + 1)$.

I'm thinking about applying the isomorphism theorem to

$f:\mathbb{Z}[X] \to \mathbb{Z}[e^{2\pi i / 5}], X \mapsto e^{2\pi i / 5}$.

Showing that $\operatorname{ker}(f) \supset (X^4 + X^3 + X^2 + X + 1)$ is straightforward:

$\operatorname{ker}(f)$ is prime, and $X^5 - 1 = (X - 1)(X^4 + X^3 + X^2 + X + 1) \in \operatorname{ker}(f)$, but $X - 1 \notin \operatorname{ker}(f)$, thus $X^4 + X^3 + X^2 + X + 1 \in \operatorname{ker}(f)$. Alternatively, and even more elementary, plugging in the value verifies that it is in the kernel.

Is there a quick way to show the reverse? Or is there another, better way to show it?

(I can't comment, so I have to answer to comments in this way: Showing irreducibility by comparing coefficients is possible, but how would it help?)

Comment: What is the definition of $f$?

Comment: @ajotatxe: I guess it is the evaluation map at $X:=\exp(2i\pi/5)$.

Comment: This is essentially checking the cyclotomic polynomial is irreducible. For a polynomial of such low degree you can write a factorization and solve for the coefficients.

Comment: Also it may simplify things to look at $\mathbb Z[X]/(X^5-1)$ as sort of a mediating step...

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Not it doesn't.  A postiori this is $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}[e^{2\pi i/5}]$ which is just more complicated.

Comment: @FanZheng This is useless advice.  In the field case this allows us to say that the kernel must contain a prime ideal, and therefore it contains a maximal ideal, so it must be the maximal ideal.  But it implies nothing here when working over the integers, without a further argument:

Comment: @HariRau-Murthy I had in mind separating two different issues here: (1) universally adding a fifth root of 1 and (2) excluding 1 which itself happens to be a solution of $X^5=1$. Both separately are more easily understood than figuring out at once why $X^4+...+X+1$ is needed, no?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე But 'figuring out why $X^4+\ldots+X+1$ is needed' isn't OP's trouble. It's pretty self-evident the connection between the two; OP's question is specifically showing that _every_ element of the evaluation map's kernel is in the ideal, and your suggestion doesn't do anything to help with that.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Oh I see my mistake now, thanks

Comment: The main point is Gauss's lemma.  See my answer.

Comment: Almost by definition $\varphi : \mathbb{Z}[X]/(f) \to\mathbb{Z}[\alpha],\varphi(P) = P(\alpha)$ is an isomorphism of (commutative) rings whenever $f \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$.

Comment: @HariRau-Murthy This is exactly what I mean, but I intend "essentially" in the sense of mathoverflow, without noting that this question has been migrated, in which case I would have said more.

Answer (score 1):

$$f:\Bbb{Z}[X]\to\Bbb{Z}\left[{e^{2\pi i\over 5}}\right]\\X\to e^{2\pi i\over 5}$$
$f$ is ring homomorphism,

$$\Bbb{Z}[X]/\langle p(x)\rangle\simeq \Bbb{Z}\left[e^{2\pi i/5}\right]$$ where $p(x)$ monic irreducible polynomial and have root $e^{2\pi i/5}$ 
we have $p(x)=x^4+x^3+x^3+x^2+x+1$

Comment: And assume that $q(X) \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ is the minimal polynomial of $e^{2i \pi / 5}$. Then $\mathbb{Z}[e^{2i \pi / 5}] \simeq \mathbb{Z}[X]/(q)$, but  $\sigma(e^{2i \pi / 5}) = e^{2i \pi k / 5}$, $k \in 1 \ldots 4$ is a ring isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[e^{2i \pi / 5}]$ to itself, therefore $\sigma(0) = \sigma(q(e^{2i \pi / 5})) = q(e^{k 2i \pi / 5})$ i.e. $e^{k 2i \pi / 5}$ is a root of $q(X)$ and $p$ divides $q$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$
$\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}$
$\newcommand{\cont}{\operatorname{cont}}$
$\newcommand{\Ker}{\operatorname{Ker}}$
Let $\phi(x)=x^4+..1$ and let $\Ker$ be the kernel of $\Z[x] \xrightarrow{evaluation} \Z[e^{2 \pi i/4}]$

**Fact**(see my comment above): The substitution map induces an iso $\Q[x]/(\phi(x)) \cong \Q[e^{2\pi i/5}]$.

**Lemma**: If $f \in \Ker$,$f$ has content 1, $\Rightarrow$ $f$ is in $(\phi) \in \Z[x]$.
Proof:

Now let $f \in \Z[x]$ satisfy $f(e^{2 \pi i/5})=0$ and also be of content 1.  Then $f =\phi h$ for some $h \in \Q[x]$.   Write $c h(x)=H(x)$ where $H(x)$ has content 1, and $c \in \Z$. Then $c=c \cont(f)=\cont(\phi)\cont(H)=1\cdot 1$. QED.

Now let $f \in Ker$ be arbitrary.  Then $f=\cont(f)  \cdot F$ where $F$ has content $1$.  $F$ is in $(\phi) \subset \Z[x]$ by the lemma, so $f$ is too.